# Leningrad Dutch against Reti

Tags: dutch-defense, reti-opening

I like playing the King's Indian Attack against just about any black setup, except for when black plays the Leningrad Dutch style setup.

I had a look at how white is dealing with this situation and it seems that the double fianchetto with white pawns on b3, c4, d4 and g3 is not bad.

My question is about the different move orders that can lead there.

After 1. Nf3, black can reach his setup via either 1. ... f5 or 1...d6.

Is there any difference between these for the white player?

In which order shall I go for the double fianchetto setup described above?

Comment: @BlindKungFuMaster: If a quick f5 is not good in this line I am fine with it. Still I have the question about the move order for c4, b3, etc if I play a double fianchetto.

Comment: If you put a pawn on d4 as mentioned you are not in King's Indian Attack or Reti.  Maybe you should first focus on what is wrong with your King's Indian Attack against the Dutch?!

Comment: @Ywapom Indeed he wouldn't be in the King's Indian Attack, but most variations of the Réti will involve white playing d4 at some point. For example, in his 2004 book entitled "The Dynamic Reti" (ISBN: 978-1857443523), GM Nigel Davies cites the following as the main line of the closed Reti: 1.Nf3 e6 2.c4 d5 3.g3 Nf6 4.Bg2 Be7 5.O-O O-O 6.b3 c5 7.e3 Nc6 8.Bb2 b6 9.Nc3 Bb7 10.cxd5 exd5 11.d4! (the exact move order might be slightly different as I'm writing this from memory, but I'm completely certain about the 11th move). White can easily make this d4 move earlier than move 11.

Answer (score 3):

After 1...d6 you could consider playing 2.e4. One of the biggest advantages of 1.Nf3 is it's flexibility and if you are looking for a quiet(ish) game then perhaps a Be2 (Classical) Pirc is your answer.

Against 1...f5 2.d3 has an excellent reputation I believe. (Idea is 2...Nf6 3.e4 and black is advised not to take the gambit pawn).
Worth noting is that 1.Nf3 f5 2.d3 Nc6!? I think the best move is 3.d4! Chess is a funny game.

If you are dead set on a double fianchetto, I guess fianchettoing the kings bishop makes sense first as you get to castle sooner (you can also consider playing b4 instead of b3 after you have castled).

Comment: This doesn't really answer the questions asked ("Is there any difference between these for the white player?" and "In which order shall I go for the double fianchetto setup described above?").